# When using setFormulas I get error Cannot find function error "object function getFontColor() {/* */}."

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script that copies down formula the length of the sheet (stitched together on the back of other SO posts I found while researching):

```
var originRange = ss.getSheetByName('data_prep').getRange('C6:I6');
var formulas = originRange.getFormulas();
var target = ss.getSheetByName('data_prep').getRange('C7:I');

  for(i in target) {
    target[i].setFormulas(formulas);
  }
```

When I run this function I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function setFormulas in object function getFontColor() {/* */}.Dismiss
```

What I had hoped/expected was for all the formulas in C6:I6 to be copied into each row starting C7 down the length of the sheet.

The function works for one row at a time. So if I set target as just C7:I7 and get rid of the for loop it works.

1. Why am I getting this getFont error?
2. How can I get my script to copy the formulas in C6:I6 down the entire sheet?
3. As an alternative to 2, how can I get my script to copy down as far as while there is data in column A?

Comment: target is an object NOT an array. and that object doesnt have a property named "1". look at the official docs for how to use a range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataPrepSheet = ss.getSheetByName('data_prep')
var originRange = dataPrepSheet.getRange('C6:I6');

var everyRow = dataPrepSheet.getMaxRows().toString();
var target = dataPrepSheet.getRange('C7:I' + everyRow);

originRange.copyTo(target);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Use the `getMaxRows()` method to get every every row in the spreadsheet, whether it's got content or not.  That returns an integer, so convert it to a string then use a text formula to create the A1 notation.

Then, don't set the formulas, use `copyTo()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've given that a try but it seems to be causing the sheet to operate so slowly to the point it's not useable. Can;t actually  tell if it's working because the sheet is still loading. Incidentally, why did my original script work when copying to one row? How come I could not loop through each row int he range?

Comment: OK, sheet loaded. It works! Not sure what flush does, read a little on it in the documentation but I don't get it? Why is it needed? Why is onOpen not enough?

Comment: `flush()` applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.  The pending changes will be applied at some point no matter what.  So, in that sense, it not "needed".  But if you have more code to run, and you want to see the formula results as the code is running, you need to use `flush()`.

Comment: If the spreadsheet is calculating thousands of rows of formulas, it will be very slow.  I would never copy formulas to rows that have no data to work on, it's just a waste of time.  If you have that much data, using a spreadsheet is going to be very "slow".  Everything is relative.  Very fast if compared to doing it manually. :)

Comment: OK thanks for the feedback. I'm going to look into making the formula copy down only so long as there are data in column A, otherwise, as you say, there is much waste going down the length of the sheet.